# font size definition problem in math mode

Tags: fonts, macros

I am defining some abbreviations to use in a very large book in order to get consistency over chapter. I have the following definition that works in regular text:

```
\newcommand{\pr}{\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont\ttfamily PROJ\normalsize\selectfont\rmfamily}
```

I need versions of these to use in math expressions. I thought I could define the following:

```
\newcommand{\prm}{\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont\mathtt PROJ\normalsize\selectfont\rmfamily}
```

but this is giving an error when I use `\prm` in a math expression indicating I can't use `\normalsize` in math expressions. So, I tried the following, which is giving errors as well:

```
\newcommand{\prm}{\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont\mathtt PROJ \fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont\textrm}
```

Any suggestions as to how I might accomplish this?

Many thanks.

Comment: you don't need to set the font and set it back again, you could just use a group, eg `\mbox{\small PROJ}` which would also work in math mode, but perhaps better `\textsc{proj}`  again that would work in math and text

Comment: If you really need those commands, try `\newcommand{\prm}{{\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont\mathtt{PROJ}}}`. But if you explain more, we could help better what output you want to produce.

Comment: Thank you I will try the new definition. Basically I want to use these abbreviations in the book so that these terms are typeset the same way across the book and they are easy to change if we need to. These abbreviations are sometimes used in regular text and sometimes in math expressions, hence the different definitions.

Comment: Look for operators.

Comment: These are relation and attribute names. I have operator definitions.